# Does the homotopy lifting property imply that the lifts of the homotopic maps are homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

The homotopy lifting property says:

> Suppose $p: \tilde X \to X$ is a covering map. Suppose $F: Y \times I \to X$ is a homotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$, and $\tilde f_0$ is a lift of $f_0$. Then there exists a unique homotopy $\tilde F: Y \times I \to \tilde X$ such that $\tilde F(s,0)=\tilde f_0(s)$ and $p \circ \tilde F = F$.

**Does this mean that the homotopy $\tilde F$ is a homotopy between $\tilde f_0$ and $\tilde f_1$, where $\tilde f_0$ is a lift of $f_0$ and $\tilde f_1$ is a lift of $f_1$?**

**Why is there no mention of $\tilde f_1$?**

Comment: $f_1$ typically has many lifts; one will be homotopic to the given lift $\tilde{f}_0$ of $f_0$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It is possible that distinct lifts of $f_1$ are homotopic (for example if $\tilde{X}$ is contractible). But fortunately that is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: You obtain a specific lift $\tilde f_1$ of $f_1$ as the "end" of the homotopy $\tilde F$, That is why it is not mentioned. An arbitrary lift of $f_1$ is not necessarily homotopic to $\tilde f_0$. Take for example $\tilde X =X \times \mathbb Z$ and $f_0 = f_1 = id_X$. Then $\tilde f_i(x) = (x,i)$ are lifts of the $f_i$, but they are not homotopic.

Comment: @PaulFrost In your example, if we have the lift $\tilde f_0(x)=(x,0)$ of $f_0=id_X$, then the unique lifted homotopy then says that $\tilde f_1$ must actually be equal to $\tilde f_0$?

Comment: Yes, that is true. But the map in my previous comment is also lift of $f_1$ which shows that non-homotopic lifts of the same map may exist.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ok I see. Going back to the theorem, we know that the lifted homotopy is unique, but is the lift $\tilde f_1$ of $f_1$ also going to be the unique lift which is homotopic to the lift $\tilde f_0$? In other words, once we have a homotopy and a lift $\tilde f_0$ of $f_0$, we get a unique lifted homotopy starting at $\tilde f_0$, and will there be a unique lift of $f_1$ that will be homotopic to $\tilde f_0$?

Comment: The point is that for any homotopy between two maps and any lift of the first map there exists a unique lifted homotopy starting with the lift of the first map and ending with a lift of the second map. The lift is then unique, but in general there are also other lifts. Such a lift is not necessarily homotopic to the lift of the first map (see my example), but if it is, which is also possible, the homotopy between the two lifts is not a lift of our initial homotopy.

Comment: @PaulFrost Got it. Thank you.